# Check Browser support for a Font using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where in User needs to select a Font from a list of specified Fonts using Javascript. I have 2 options here:

1 - To provide list of fonts in a dropdown. But the problem here is how to get that list for a particular browsers.

2 - To allow user to enter font name in a text box. Here the problem is how to validate if the font name entered is supported by the browser.

I need help to check if there is any API i can use to check for browser supported fonts.

Comment: And you want us to do this for you?

Comment: I have not tried anything till now. I want to know if there in any API in Javascript to check for browser supported fonts.

Comment: I guess you people are not clear with the question..  In simple words I need to show a dropdown of list of fonts based on the browser support dynamically.. Help me find out  how to do that??

Comment: Check out http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Comment: Thanks Rick.. that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Download the font files from Google Font which you like to keep in the list and load that font using js. Using Jquery

```
$("head")
.prepend("<style type=\"text/css\" id=\"selected_font\">" +
    "@font-face {\n" +
    "\tfont-family: \"myFont\";\n" +
    "\tsrc: url('location/To/Your/Font.otf') ;\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "\tp.myClass {\n" +
    "\tfont-family: myFont !important;\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "</style>");
```

when user changes font from drop-downs,remove this style element

```
$('#selected_font').remove();
```

and again append the style tag with the selected font name and path

```
 $("head")
    .prepend("<style type=\"text/css\" id=\"selected_font\">" +
        "@font-face {\n" +
        "\tfont-family: \"myNewFont\";\n" +
        "\tsrc: url('location/To/Your/newFont.otf') ;\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "\tp.myClass {\n" +
        "\tfont-family: myNewFont !important;\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "</style>");
```

Comment: This should be ok..  But don't the browsers support a set of fonts by default?? Is there any way to check that?

Comment: If you have a generic solution then why would you go with the complexity of finding browser specific fonts?

Comment: See your generic solution is fine in case if browser doesnot support any font at all..  Then you can keep on leading new otf files and maintain a list. But in case when browser also supports some fonts already why do you need to load .otf for those fonts?